# Как добавить meta данные комментария если я использую вывод с помощью wp_list_comments()?

Tags: wordpress

Как добавить meta данные комментария если я использую вывод с помощью `wp_list_comments()`?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать параметр walker и создать свой класс для обработки вывода комментариев на основе `Walker_Comment` переопределив нужный вам метод
https://wp-kama.ru/function/Walker_Comment